# Obtaining a Previously Constructed Function as Desired Output

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, function-construction, output-formatting

I was playing around with some Generalized Trigonometric Functions defined as follows;

```
 w[n_] := E^((2*\[Pi]*I)/n)

 Ncos[n_, x_] := Expand[(1/n)*Sum[E^(x*w[2 n]^(2 k + 1)), {k, 0, n - 1}]]

 Nsin[n_, j_, x_] := Expand[(1/(n*w[2 n]^j))*Sum[w[n]^(-j*k) E^(x*w[2 n]^(2 k + 1)), {k, 0, n - 1}]]
```

These functions act like the familiar trigonometric functions and have the property that

$$\frac{d^{2n}}{dx^{2n}}f(x)=f(x)$$
or
$$f^{(n)}(x)+f(x)=0$$

As I was testing with paper and pencil I wrote up the above functions when I got home to my computer and observed that these relations hold.  However, when I employ the derivative function $D$ in Mathematica, it will give the derivative in terms of the expanded function.  For example, if I type in

```
 D[Ncos[3,x],x]
```

It returns 
$$-\frac{e^{-x}}{3}+\frac{1}{3}e^{{\frac{-i\pi}{3}-e^{\frac{-i\pi}{3}}}x}+\frac{1}{3}e^{{\frac{i\pi}{3}-e^{\frac{i\pi}{3}}}x}$$

The derivative should equal -Nsin[3,2,x], and when you input

```
 -Nsin[3,2,x]
```

it returns

$$-\frac{e^{-x}}{3}-\frac{1}{3}e^{{\frac{-4i\pi}{3}-e^{\frac{-i\pi}{3}}}x}-\frac{1}{3}e^{{\frac{-2i\pi}{3}-e^{\frac{i\pi}{3}}}x}$$

While Mathematica doesn't output the same form, subtracting the two yields 0, proving their equality...

My question is this.  Is there a way to get mathematica, when I input

```
 D[Ncos[3,x],x]
```

to output

```
 -Nsin[3,2,x]
```

Or for other derivative, for example, if I input

```
 D[D[D[Ncos[3,x],x],x],x]
```

I would like to see

```
 -Ncos[3,x]
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Could you check your results? I copied your definitions and ran them, and I don't get the results you posted for `-Nsin[3, 2, x]` (your result seems to be missing a few $x$ here and there) or for `D[Ncos[3, x]]` (your result seems to contain a $(-1)^{1/3}$ factor in two terms that I cannot reproduce. Not only that, but if I run `D[Ncos[3, x]] - (-Nsin[3, 2, x]) // FullSimplify` I do NOT obtain zero, no matter what I try for simplification.

Comment: Did you include the root of unity definition?  Mine definitely works, and I verified with with >D[Nsin[3,2,x],x]-Nsin[3,1,x] // FullSimplify

Comment: I could email you my notebook....

Comment: I edited the formulas (removed the simplify command) and reposted.  I am definitely getting the correct results...

Comment: @MarcoB have you retried with the new formulas i edited in the question?

Comment: Do you have a reference for these formulae you derived? Your first two equations are apparently inconsistent: you take the $2n$-th derivative in the first and the $n$-th derivative in the second.

Comment: They are higher analogues of trig functions.  For example, $$D^4[\cos(x)]=\cos(x)$$ and $$D^2[\cos(x)]+\cos(x)=0$$Nothing out of the ordinary here.  How are they incosistent?

Comment: I noticed, @MarcoB, that you said you entered D[Ncos[3,x]], but you need to identify the variable of differentiation in your argument, so it should be D[Ncos[3,x],x], not just D[Ncos[3,x]]